# Excluding module creation in Terraform without using count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I have the following two modules in my main.tf file as follows :

```
module "glue_connection_component_anon" {
  count = var.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 0
  source           = "../../modules/glue_connector"
  connector_config = local.glue_connectors_config_anon
  default_tags     = local.default_tags
}
    
    
module "glue_connection_component_live" {
  count = var.environment == "live" ? 1 : 0
  source           = "../../modules/glue_connector"
  connector_config = local.glue_connectors_config_live
  default_tags     = local.default_tags
}
```

I initially wanted to make use of  a for_each statement but it doesn't seem to be working as expected :

```
module "glue_connection_component_anon" {
  for_each          = var.environment == "dev" ? { "dev" : 1 } : {}
  source            = "../../modules/glue_connector"
  connector_config  = local.glue_connectors_config_anon
  default_tags      = local.default_tags
}
```

I would rather make use of a for_each statement rather than using count as it comes with it's own issues to do with indexing.

I am seeing the following error :

```
Error: Secrets Manager Secret "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:596459206669:secret:dev/rds/replica-SfiJXX" not found
│ 
│   with data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_rds_dev,
│   on data_secret_rds.tf line 16, in data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_rds_dev":
│   16: data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_rds_dev" {
```

I understand the secret does not currently exist but how can I make terraform ignore reading the secret itself if the environment is equal to live. My secrets.tf file is as follows :

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_rds_dev" {
  arn = local.secret_rds_dev_arn
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret_rds_dev" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_rds_dev.id
}
```

Comment: What happens with the second approach? Are there any errors?

Comment: The `for_each` should work fine. Please edit your question to explain exactly why it "doesn't seem to be working". Although I will say, given that you want to create 0 or 1, based on a single string, `count` makes more sense.

Comment: @MarkB - I have now updated my question with the error i am seeing.

Comment: That error is **completely unrelated** to the code you posted originally in your question! The data source isn't in the module you are adding the `count ` or `for_each` to. If you don't want a data source to be used in a particular scenario, put a `count` in the data source to control its usage.

Comment: where the module code?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with indexing is a non-issue if you're using count as a conditional.

Indexing issues with state is only relevant if you're using count to create a list of resources. In that case, the index matters and can potentially break your state.

But for your particular use case, it's completely a non issue, and it's favorable to use count instead of for_each if you're using it as a conditional statement.

Comment: When you say Indexing issues with state is only relevant if you're using count to create a list of resources. Is there any reading i can take a look at as i may need to do this in the future

Comment: Here's a quick example. Lets say you have number_of_instances = 5. You create a list of ec2 instances using a count, where count = var.number_of_instances. Now, lets say you need to reduce the count to 4, but you want to remove the middle instance. This is where count starts to cause issues with your state, because your state is bounded by your index.

Comment: I don't know of any reading off the top of my head that explains this problem.

Comment: That makes sense. If i had 5 number of instances and then i wanted the count to be 4 , that would essentially change the index of all the instances. I am assuming count will remove the last item in the index and not the first by default ?

Comment: Yeah it'll remove the last since it's bounded by the index, so index 4 turns into 3 etc. 

Which can be fine, but the real issue comes with removing or moving resources in the middle, or the first.

Comment: Is it possible to remove or move resource in the middle or the first ? What is your workaround for this ? I will possibly have to deal with this scenario in the future when it comes to EC2 Instances

Comment: It is possible. You would have to state mv your resources around but be very careful not to override. for example: terraform state mv 0 6 (6 is a temp location), terraform state mv 2 0 (moving 2nd element to 0), terraform state mv 6 2 (moving the initial 0 to 2)